# Leaflet Control Search: open Popup for search result

Tags: search, popup, leaflet

I'm using the wonderful plugin [Leaflet.Control.Search](http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/) in order to search for markers (from a geoJson marker group) on my map – which works great.

I only have one simple question now:
how can I open a popup for the search result marker?
I'm using custom marker icons with popups (which open on click) already bound to them  – but I would like to open the respective popup automatically once it has been found via the search.

My code looks like this:

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({layer: markers2, propertyName: 'Name', circleLocation:true});

    searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function(e) {

            e.layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name).openPopup();

    }).on('search_collapsed', function(e) {
            markers2.resetStyle(layer);
    });

    map.addControl( searchControl );  //inizialize search control
```

and thought it might work with that line:

```
e.layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name).openPopup();
```

but unfortunately it doesn't.. ;)

–

Oh, and a second question: at the moment I'm searching only in 1 geoJson layer (*"markers2"*) – does anyone know whether it's possible to search in multiple layers at once?

Any suggestions? I'd be grateful for any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to do e.layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name).addTo(map).openPopup(); I think you have to tell it where to open up. So something like addTo() or openOn() might work. Check the docs [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the pointer! Your suggestion sounds about right, but it didn't seem to work that way.. 
hm, at some point before the search code above i already define the popup contents, so I guess I wouldn't necessarily have to repeat that content for the search popup, i'd just have to tell it to open the popup.. but how?! ; )

Comment: the code for the popups (before the search) is like this:

var markers2 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
 var geoJsonLayer2 = L.geoJson(data, {
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name);
     }
...

Comment: got it: it works like this: e.layer.openPopup().openOn(map);

Answer (score 3):

got it: it works like this: e.layer.openPopup().openOn(map);

Comment: as for my second question, does anyone have a hint for me?

At the moment I'm searching only in 1 geoJson layer `L.Control.Search({layer: markers2, propertyName…` – does anyone know whether it's possible to search in multiple layers at once?
I tried it like this: `{layer: (markers1, markers2), propertyName…` which isn't working…

Answer (score 1):

event.layer is set only for preloaded layer, if you search marker by ajax,jsonp or callData.. event.layer is undefined.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
            marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        }
    });

map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);

var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({layer: geojsonLayer, initial: false});

controlSearch.on('search_locationfound', function(event) {
    event.layer.openPopup();
});
```

Look at GeoJSON demo:
https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geojson-layer.html

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I was looking for an answer, and here is my solution for it

```
searchControl.on("search:locationfound", function (e) {
    if (e.layer._popup) e.layer.openPopup();
  });
```

Comment: I'm happy I found this post.  This is exactly what I was trying to figure out for the past 3 days. Works perfect!